# Find a paper about portfolio management

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory

Where to find the following paper of the noble prize Paul Samuelson (2003) “When and Why Mean-Variance Analysis Generically Fails,”. I was looking for it desperately on Google and Google Scholar but no results. Please help in case you have seen it.

Answer (score 3):

This [pdf](http://research.stlouisfed.org/wp/2007/2007-016.pdf) says on page two that the paper was never published. I don't know the reason but you could try to mail the authors of the papers were the article is mentioned. Since it was never published it might be less encumbered by copyright than usual.